# How can I configure all the Catalyst actions in a given controller using Config::General?

Tags: perl, model-view-controller, configuration, catalyst

I want to configure all the actions in my controller using my app's config file. According to [Catalyst::Controller](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/Catalyst-Runtime/lib/Catalyst/Controller.pm#action) I can do this in the controller itself:

```
__PACKAGE__->config(
    action => {
        '*' => { Chained => 'base', Args => 0  },
    },
 );
```

So I tried this in my config:

```
<controller Foo>
    <action "*">                                                                
        Chained base
        Args 0
    </action>
</controller>
```

But I get this error on startup:

```
Couldn't load class (MyApp) because: Action "*" is not available from 
controller MyApp::Controller::Foo at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Catalyst/
Controller.pm line 193
```

It does the same without the quotes around the asterisk. How should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in [The Definitive Guide to Catalyst](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781430223658)

Grab the downloadable source from that page, unzip it, go to the DwarfChains application in chapter 7, then add the following to dwarfchains.conf:

```
 <Controller People>
 <action get_ready>
  PathPart nama
 </action>
 </Controller>

 <Controller People::Info>
 <action get_info_ready>
  PathPart siapa
 </action >
 <action create>
  PathPart lagi
 </action >
 <action delete>
  PathPart mengusir
 </action >
 </Controller>
```

That should more or less demonstrate how to override dispatch by configuration.

Comment: My point was how cal I configure all actions, using a wildcard. In the controller config I can do (from http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/Catalyst-Runtime/lib/Catalyst/Controller.pm#action):
'*' => { Chained => 'base', Args => 0  },
But using Config::General I get the error above

Comment: What I'd do in your case is to make a minimal test case using the inline controller configuration as documented, then serialise the config using the following command to see what Config::General is expecting to see:  perl -Ilib -e 'use MyApp; use 
             Config::General; Config::General->new->save_file("myapp_testing.conf", 
             MyApp->config);'

Comment: Sounded like a great idea but unfortunately didn't help. Config::General output: <action><*>Chained base</*></action> which is what I expected. But, putting that into my application config raised the same exception in Catalyst as documented above. Seems the problem is with Catalyst's parsing of the config.

Comment: Congratulations for finding the second bug reported on Stack Overflow!  Please report it at https://rt.cpan.org/Dist/Display.html?Name=Catalyst

Comment: sorry, incorrect link.  Correct place to report the bug is https://rt.cpan.org/Dist/Display.html?Name=Catalyst-Runtime

Comment: Thanks! Yes - I put it in on Saturday: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=62577

Comment: Going to accept this as an answer - as in, the answer is: it's a bug!

Comment: Actually I think it's a bug in Config::General